# Unable to send record for docusign signature

Tags: salesforce, docusignapi, apex, docusignconnect, docusignapextoolkit

I am using Docusign for Esignature Salesforce Managed package. Enabled send as System user option with a docusign admin user. but when I am trying to send the record for signature through apex I am facing below error "A Mergefield value for a tab could not be retrieved. Unable to connect to the service. Failed to connect to the salesforce service"

When i try to send the document as a docusign user, the record is sending succesfully.

Tried logging out and connecting the account.
Tried deleting the app at docusign and connected again.
checked whether user has access to the fields. User has access to all the merge fields.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at the following article that I found on the DocuSign Support website, which addresses the same or a very a similar error:
[DocuSign eSignature for Salesforce - INVALID_FIELD - A merge field value for a Tab could not be retrieved](https://support.docusign.com/s/articles/DocuSign-for-Salesforce-INVALID-FIELD)

In summary, the article suggests the following steps to troubleshoot your error:

***Salesforce administrator permissions are required to resolve this issue. If you are not a Salesforce administrator, you will need to engage an administrator for assistance.***

1. Confirm DocuSign is able to access Salesforce. The best to do this is to log into Salesforce, as an administrator, navigate to the **DocuSign Admin > Account > Modify Account Configuration**. Follow the prompt to reconfigure your credentials.
2. Create a new envelope and attempt reproduce the issue. If the error does not occur again, the issue is fixed! If the error still occurs, take note of the fields called out in the error.
3. Return to Salesforce and authenticate as the DocuSign Connect user. Navigate to the record you are attempting to send from and make note of which fields you are unable to access. You will need to grant the DocuSign Connect user permissions to these fields. More information on this process can be found in the article [DfS - DocuSign eSignature for Salesforce - Drop Down List of Salesforce Objects Omit Some Values](https://support.docusign.com/s/articles/DfS-DocuSign-for-Salesforce-Drop-Down-List-of-Salesforce-Objects-Omit-Some-Values)